# How to deal with the "academic" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We current have an [academic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic) tag, which probably doesn't make much sense given that our SE topic (and title) is “Academia”. So, two questions:

- Can we get rid of it? By retagging its 11 questions, possibly by mod mass-retagging (which doesn't bump the questions, as far as I remember).
- Is there a way to blacklist it?

Comment: Having looked at the questions tagged by [academic] it is clear it has not been used for any specific purpose and is completely superfluous. A good start is perhaps untagging the questions?

Answer (score 5):

I've slowly retagged all the [academic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic) questions. Now, a request to the mods: **could you blacklist it?** I don't think it can ever be useful as a tag, so blacklisting it will avoid it reappearing in the future.

Comment: No problem for black listing, I just haven't figured out how to do it yet :)